# Is there a way to define queryparams for all endpoints in javax.ws.rs?

Tags: java, swagger, jax-rs, openapi

I am trying to document an already existing application using javax.ws.rs annotations to define what headers (@HeaderParam) and parameters (@QueryParam) a specific endpoint needs. This information would them be used to generate a swagger page for the application.

```
public Response SampleFunction(@RequestBody(...),
                               @QueryParam(...),
                               @HeaderParam(...),
                               @HeaderParam(...),
                               @HeaderParam(...),
                               etc etc etc){
   return doStuff()
}
```

I have identified a set of "@HeaderParam" which are required for all endpoints.
I need to know if there is any way for me to define the @HeaderParam only once and use that definition for all endpoints and, since this is an already existing application, I need to do this change without any major code refactorization.

Comment: Which generator tool/plugin do you use to generate your swagger spec? Probably it can be configured there.

Comment: @wimdetr Payara generates the OpenApi file which we then use in a swagger.ui file to generate the interface with the endpoints.

Comment: What kind of header parameters? If those headers are used for authentication, you should define them using security-specific annotations such as [`@SecurityScheme`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#security-annotations).

Comment: @AshenWaltz is following documentation & example of any help? https://blog.payara.fish/microprofile-openapi-in-the-payara-platform https://github.com/payara/Payara-Examples/tree/master/microprofile/openapi-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We believe to have found a solution for this matter.
By declaring the @HeaderParam globally they appear for all endpoints without having to repeat the declaration for each endpoint.
Something like this:

```
@Path("/")
public class myClass{

   @HeaderParam("Parameter_one")
   @Parameter(example = "example_one)
   Type parameter_one

   @HeaderParam("Parameter_two")
   @Parameter(example = "example_two)
   Type parameter_two

   public Response SampleFunction(@RequestBody(...),
                              etc etc etc){
      return doStuff()
   }
}
```

In this particular case, Parameter_one and Parameter_two will become available on the Swagger page for all endpoints.